# bootstrap: same html is not rendered correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 bootstrap ul's and one is beautified and the other one is not, my problem is why the first ul is not rendering correctly is is not beautified , what is wrong ? How you can see in fiddle example in second ul which is the same with first ul nut beautified te spaces are added correctly...

> Same html but not beautified

```
<ul id="handlers-list" class="list-group">
        <li id="GET___asdasd" class="list-group-item"><span>/asdasd</span><span class="label label-primary">GET</span><span class="label label-primary">html</span><span style="display:none;">asdasdasd</span><button id="hnd-show-ct" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></li>
    </ul>
```

> Same HTML but beautified is render correctly

```
<ul id="handlers-list" class="list-group">
        <li id="GET___asdasd" class="list-group-item">
            <span>/asdasd</span>
            <span class="label label-primary">GET</span>
            <span class="label label-primary">html</span>
            <span style="display:none;">asdasdasd</span>
            <button id="hnd-show-ct" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></li>
    </ul>
```

**[Here is a small js example:](http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/249/)**

Comment: If you give space between Get & html span's You can get Spaces as you want.. Its because Browsers condense multiple whitespace characters to a single space when rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White-spaces between inline elements are transformed into one space. The reasoning is that inline elements might be interspersed with regular inner text of the parent element. So give space or enter the span in new line to get expected result

Try like this:

```
<li id="GET___asdasd" class="list-group-item"><span>/asdasd</span> <span class="label label-primary">GET</span><span class="label label-primary">html</span> <span style="display:none;">asdasdasd</span> 
        <button id="hnd-show-ct" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

could be due to your code structure. if you structure the top one like the bottom one then it should work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQg4s.png

heres a screen shot of what i changed

Answer (score 0):

Continuous html markup like in the first example removes the space between elements. 
The second example has spaces in the markup which leads to proper aligned buttons.